# Can Batch Normalization replace tanh in RNN?

Tags: rnn, batch-normalization

## Question

Can Batch Normalization (`BN`) be inserted in RNN after $x_t@W_{xh}$, and after $h_{t-1}@W_{hh}$ to remove $f=tanh$ and bias $b_h$? If possible, will this eliminate both exploding and vanishing gradient problems?

[image]

I believe the effect of `tanh` to adjust the values from `[-inf, +inf]` into `(-1, 1)` can be replaced with the standardization in `BN` and it makes the bias unnecessary at  $x_t@W_{xh}$ and $h_{t-1}@W_{hh}$.

- [Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167)

[image]

The auto differentiation of tanh should be able to be replaced with those of BN too.

### Background

It is said tanh addresses the exploding gradient problem in RNN, hence it is being used.

- [Why do we need second tanh() in LSTM cell](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/368746/105137)

> An issue with recurrent neural networks is potentially exploding
> gradients given the repeated back-propagation mechanism.
>
> After the addition operator the absolute value of c(t) is potentially
> larger than 1. Passing it through a tanh operator ensures the values
> are scaled between -1 and 1 again, thus increasing stability during
> back-propagation over many timesteps.

- [[D] Why do you use tanh in a RNN?](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/9elxs8/d_why_do_you_use_tanh_in_a_rnn/)

> The vanishing gradient problem is the main problem in RNN. Also, to
> keep the gradient in the linear region of the activation function, we
> need a function whose second derivative can sustain for a long range
> before going to zero. Tanh is pretty good with these properties.

Batch Normalization can address both exploding and vanishing gradient problems.

- [Batch Normalization: The Greatest Breakthrough in Deep Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-normalization-the-greatest-breakthrough-in-deep-learning-77e64909d81)

> **Solving the vanishing gradient problem**. Although internal covariate
> shift may not improve accuracy, it is somewhat involved in the
> vanishing gradient problem. When the distribution of inputs shifts, it
> will fall prone to inherently smaller gradient updates due to the
> activation functions (for example, sigmoid, which puts miniscule
> values at anything ±2.5, or ReLU, which sets any x < 0 to 0). Batch
> normalization helps make sure that the signal is heard and not
> diminished by shifting distributions from the end to the beginning of
> the network during backpropagation.
>
> **Solving the exploding gradient problem**. As batch normalization smooths
> the optimization landscape, it gets rid of the extreme gradients that
> accumulate, leading to the elimination of the major weight
> fluctuations that result from gradient build-up. This dramatically
> stabilizes learning.

## Research

There are several articles and papers which suggest it is possible but could not find a simple implementation diagram or a code example.

- [Is it normal to use batch normalization in RNN & LSTM? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51178579)

> For RNNs, this means computing the relevant statistics over the mini-batch and the time/step dimension, so the normalization is applied only over the vector depths. This also means that you only batch normalize the transformed input (so in the vertical directions, e.g. BN(W_x * x)) since the horizontal (across time) connections are time-dependent and shouldn't just be plainly averaged.

- [Recurrent Batch Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09025)

> We propose a reparameterization of LSTM that brings the benefits of batch normalization to recurrent neural networks. Whereas previous works only apply batch normalization to the input-to-hidden transformation of RNNs, we demonstrate that it is both possible and beneficial to batch-normalize the hidden-to-hidden transition, thereby reducing internal covariate shift between time steps.

> Although batch normalization has demonstrated significant training speed-ups and generalization
> benefits in feed-forward networks, it is proven to be difficult to apply in recurrent architectures (Laurent et al., 2016; Amodei et al., 2015). It has found limited use in stacked RNNs, where the normalization is applied “vertically”, i.e. to the input of each RNN, but not “horizontally” between
> timesteps. RNNs are deeper in the time direction, and as such batch normalization would be most
> beneficial when applied horizontally. However, Laurent et al. (2016) hypothesized that applying
> batch normalization in this way hurts training because of exploding gradients due to repeated rescaling.
> Our findings run counter to this hypothesis. We show that it is both possible and highly beneficial to
> apply batch normalization in the hidden-to-hidden transition of recurrent models.

- [Layer Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450)

Answer (score 0):

Vertically BN is OK, but horizontally after hidden state vector we need layer normalization instead of tanh and that what I will try today. Then a 0,2 dropout for the hidden state I guess